# Winapi: createWindow in plugin

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm developing a plugin (a dll that is loaded by other app). There's a special function that should return `HWND` so that app can show a dialog. The problem is that I don't know from where I can get the `hInstance` (it's not passed as a parameter to the function).

Looks like I'm not understanding something, I'm new to all this stuff, so forgive if the question is silly.

**UPD**: tried to get hInstance with `getModuleHandle`:

```
void* createLoginDialog() {
    HINSTANCE hIns = (HINSTANCE) GetModuleHandle(L"comapping");
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Popup",
                        L"Enter login",
                        WS_POPUP,
                        20,
                        20,
                        20,
                        20,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hIns,
                        NULL);
    return hWnd;
}
```

I'm still getting Access Violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways to get it:

- The first argument passed to your DllMain() entrypoint, cast to HINSTANCE
- GetModuleHandle() using your DLL name, cast to HINSTANCE
- VirtualQuery(), passing the address of your function.  Cast the returned MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.BaseAddress to HINSTANCE.  Works on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use `GetModuleHandle`, still geting Access violation. I've updated question

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `hInstance` argument is optional. This means that it's valid to pass `NULL` here. However, as Simon Richter points out in the comments to this answer, the argument may only be `NULL` the window class is registered globally.

If you're writing a DLL, you may just as well define a [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry point function yourself. This function is called by Windows, passing the handle of your function as the first arugment. You can memorize this handle somewhere to reuse it when creating your window.

Comment: It is only optional if the class is registered as global, which is bad style. Using the DLL's instance is the correct approach, as it also tells the system that the DLL is needed for this window to operate correctly.

Comment: @Frerich, passing `NULL` causes memory violation

Comment: @SimonRichter,what do you mean by "using DLL's instance"?

Comment: @SimonRichter: Ah, interesting - I wasn't aware of this. I never passed `NULL` myself, so I never noticed this requirement. Thanks for pointing this out; I will augment my answer to mention this requirement.

Comment: When you register the window class, you should use the instance handle of the module containing the window procedure -- if that is your DLL, use the handle you were given in `DllMain`. The same handle needs to be passed to `CreateWindow`.

Comment: @SimonRichter: I see; so assuming one doesn't use a custom class and/or a custom window procedure, it should be safe to use `GetClassInfo` to get the `HINSTANCE` handle of whatever window class is used, and then pass that handle to `CreateWindow`?